# Merging Database Modifications - CVS

Tags: git, mysql, svn, database, cvs

I'm working on a project using `git` for version handling. What is the best approach to include a mysql database in the cvs?

For example, if I checkout the database and install it at home, make some changes and check it in, I would like the changes I've made to be merged into the database. And I would like to be able to rollback these changes.

Comment: That depends on the database.

Answer (score 1):

With the projects I've seen and the databases I've managed, usually the best way to do this is to script the scheme and then include the scheme with the commit along with a script of the changes you make. That also makes it rather easy to compare changes.

Also look here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173/how-do-i-version-my-ms-sql-database-in-svn